# Making CheckBox Appear Enabled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

How would I go about making a disabled checkbox appear as though it is enabled.
I have tried setting the opacity, foreground, background, and masks, but to no avail:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxDisplay" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I could easily just give the checkboxes an event to disallow people to change it's state by just changing it back, but that seems like cheating.

Comment: This reeks of bad usability.

Comment: why would you want to do this..  can you explain your illogical approach to use..?

Comment: @MethodMan I have a "How To" section to my application. It will explain things such as "if checkbox is null, this will happen, if true, this, if false that". And I just wanted to display pretty pictures for any non-programmers to understand what a "null checkbox" is.
The thing is, if i disable it, it's hard to see, and to an end user it might look different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would probably just use this:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="True" IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False"/>
```

Comment: Well, i sure hope it does!